# Get coordinates from map Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrape

I am trying to scrape this site:
https://www.spitogatos.gr/aggelia/1112580220
and also I want to scrape the location and find how much is the distance from the metro station to the House.

I did an inspect

`<path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="rgba(113, 100, 243, 0.25)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#7164f3" fill-opacity="0.15" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M309.6364977415651,195.17018181830645a80,80 0 1,0 160,0 a80,80 0 1,0 -160,0 "></path>`

but the values are a bit hazy for me, because these coordinates is not for a big map but very specific coordinates for a partion of the global map.

I am searching if there is a way which I can found the global coordinates of the house e.g. a house in Greece will be x = 200 y = 8000 and a house in Sweeden will be x = 200 y = 12000( if we presume the global map to be 2d ).

thank you in advance

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I don't have started coded, because before I starting code I must find what I must scrape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `<script>` element that among others contain latitude and longitude. In this particular case: `longitude:23.800493,latitude:38.047432`

Comment: Hello, thank for the comment but this longitude and latitude is for a very specific region like a square but these coordiantes are global? like for a house in sweeden will be latitude  = 10000? I think this latitude is for a very specific window 
edit1, I checked and other house has the same longitude & latitude

Comment: @georgekasa What I am talking about is not the attributes of the `<path>` tag, I'm talking about the `<script>` tag, you can find it if you open the page source and search for the word "latitude". These coordinates are global.